# Dynamically add to the first collection in a nested collection VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, collections, nested

I have a nested collection and I would like to be able to loop through the parent collection, adding to each child collection dynamically. Please refer to the example below:

```
Dim parent, child1, child2, child3 as New Collection
parent.add child1
parent.add child2
parent.add child3

for i = 1 to parent.count
    parent(i).Add "This is data in each child collection"
next i
```

Is this possible to do? The above code will return an error saying an object is required. In my project, the parent collection holds about 20 different child collections, all which will be of different sizes. I would prefer to not have to manually write out the addition codes for each child. Any advice on how to move forward would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get rid of the error, type:

```
Dim parent As New Collection, child1 As New Collection, child2 As New Collection, child3 As New Collection
```

since every variable must be declared explicitly otherwise it's assumed of `Variant` type
and a `Variant` variable doesn't have any `Add` method

Comment: Thank you! Frustrating that you cannot do multiple at one time and you need to declare each one

Comment: you are welcome. it is a little frustrating but, combined with the use of `Option Explicit` gives you much more control over your code and shorten down both debugging and maintaining time